# Elisp Regex Match Commas Outside of Parenthesis

Tags: regex, emacs

I'm having an issue trying to get regex grouping to occur correctly. I have an string, say:

`dtASDF[a, b, c]`

I use the expression:

`dt\\(.*\\)\\[\\(.*\\), \\(.*\\), \\(.*\\)\\]`

And it groups the `a`, `b`, and `c` seperatly, which is perfect. The issue is that the string might be:

`dtASDF[a, .(b, c), .(d, e)]`

In which case the above expression doesn't work, since it's just looking for commas. So the question is, since emacs doesn't have lookarounds, is there a way to group by comma seperation, but not if the commas are between parenthesis?

In other words, the grouping here should be: `a`, `.(b, c)`, `.(d, e)`.

I'm aware similar questions exist on SO, but I couldn't find one relevant for elisp regex, which is tricky as it doesn't feature lookarounds that are typically  used for this sort of thing.

Comment: No dice. I think you need those double escapes in emacs.

Comment: Yeah that's not doing it either. That's not matching anything. Elisp is weird about \\ vs \
The question could probably be answered with a simpler example, in elisp, filter `(asdf, asdf), asdf` into two groups: `(asdf, asdf)` and `asdf`

Comment: In my example, `\[.*?\]` matches just the periods in `dtASDF[a, .(b, c), .(d, e)]`.
`\\[.*?\\]` matches everything insde and including `[...]`

Answer (score 2):

How about this as the grouping pattern?

```
"\\(\\.([^)]*)\\|.*?\\)"
```

So in full:

```
"dt\\(.*\\)\\[\\(\\.([^)]*)\\|.*?\\), \\(\\.([^)]*)\\|.*?\\), \\(\\.([^)]*)\\|.*?\\)\\]"
```

n.b. If you want to get verbose-but-readable with the `rx` macro, you can write that as:

```
(rx "dt" (group (zero-or-more not-newline)) "["
    (group (or (seq ".(" (zero-or-more (not (any ")"))) ")")
               (minimal-match (zero-or-more not-newline))))
    ", "
    (group (or (seq ".(" (zero-or-more (not (any ")"))) ")")
               (minimal-match (zero-or-more not-newline))))
    ", "
    (group (or (seq ".(" (zero-or-more (not (any ")"))) ")")
               (minimal-match (zero-or-more not-newline))))
    "]")
```

Comment: :thumbsup: Thank you. Regex will forever be a mystery to me.

Comment: I highly recommend `M-x re-builder` (and see also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454 regarding that).

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, this doesn't work for everything I need. It solves my example; but what if we had:
`dt[a, .(b = mean(c, d), d), .(e, f)]`
The second interior set of parens break it.

Comment: I'm afraid that you *cannot* use a regular expression to match arbitrary balanced pairs.

Comment: You would instead want to write elisp code to parse it, using the likes of the `forward-sexp` function to move across a balanced expression.  (Which would be a different question.)